# Dapper Oracle Number(10,0) is returned as Decimal Parser error

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I have a POCO:

```
public class Role
{
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

The Oracle table is `Id NUMBER(10,0)` and `Name VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)`

Dapper inserts fine but when I read the records it bring the Id as decimal and I get a parser error. And NO, I can't change the Int32 Id to decimal Id in POCO class.

Comment: Can you change the Oracle `Id NUMBER(10,0)` to `INTEGER`? or change the query to something like `SELECT CAST(Id AS INTEGER) FROM ...`

Comment: Looks like `NUMBER(10,0)` is an `Int64` [Discussed here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15604).  Converting it back is probably causing the decimal conversion.

Comment: I tired and still returns as decimal. "SELECT CAST(ID AS INTEGER) as \"ID\", NAME, DESCRIPTION,ORDINAL FROM";

Comment: If you change it to `NUMBER(9,0)` does that work?

Comment: Yes, I still get "Error parsing column 0 (ID=63 - Decimal)"

Comment: If you are using ODP.NET as Oracle DB Provider, Number(9,0) should map to int32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex I installed ODP.net and it worked.